# Problem posting to datastore with deferred.defer tasks

Tags: python, google-app-engine, scheduled-tasks, datastore, deferred

I am trying to do this on Google App Engine in Python:

```
def add_to_db(person):
     a = PersonDb(key_name = person)
     # get some data
     data1 = a.name
     data2 = a.age
     a.put()

for person in people:
    deferred.defer(add_to_db, person, _queue="myque")
```

When I run the above code via a cron job it does not work. The file executes without error, The tasks (there are 200 strings in list 'People') get added to the queue correctly and trickle through correctly. But the database PersonDb does not get updated. I know the function works (the above is simplified) because this works:

```
for person in people:
     add_to_db(person)
```

The above 2 lines of code works, and the database gets updated, but I need to run this as a deferred task. Any suggestions?

**UPDATE**: I am getting this in the log:
File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\deferred\deferred.py", line 129, in run
    raise PermanentTaskFailure(e)
PermanentTaskFailure: 'module' object has no attribute 'add_to_db'

Comment: You're evidently leaving out a lot that's important - what is `a`? We really need to see your _actual_ code to help. There's practically no point in deferring a datastore put, though - it gains you very little, and may even lose you some performance.

Comment: Your queue name should be passed as `_queue`, not `queue`.

Comment: I have to run this as a deferred task because the part of the code '#get some data' is really expensive and would take more than 30 seconds per 'person'.

Comment: `a` is a model class? Or a model _instance_? As I say, we need to see your actual code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably happening because the function you are trying to defer (`add_to_db`) is defined in the request handler.  Move `add_to_db` to another module (a different python file) and import it from there (`from myfuncs import add_to_db`).

This limitation is mentioned in the limitations section of the deferred [article](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/deferred.html).